# Highchart: Custom Fixed Placement chart

Tags: highcharts

I need to implement this chart.
[image]
I have been able to achieve till this:
[image]

I'm not able to implement 3 things:

1. Roundness only at 1 side (borderRadius round both side). (Implmeneted using rounded corner plugin)
2. That thick blue line at the end of the bar.
3. The Dashed line from bar to the x axis.

Working Demo: [JsFiddle][3]

```
  [3]: https://jsfiddle.net/Shadab_faiz/8eauv34t/5/
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your attempt with the sample data on some online editor?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Added link to js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

1. Unwanted roundness is defined in the second `series` config object - remove it. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3e90sjmv/
2. You can use the bullet graph to achieve it: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bullet-graph
3. You can use the SVERenderer tool to create this custom path: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path - this functionality might be attached inside the render callback: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: for 2nd, is there any  option other than bullect graph.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz you can also use the SVGRenderer tool to render this path